# How can I disable MTP/PTP over USB in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mtp

I'm trying to lock down and secure some of my computers, and I've been able to disable USB Mass Storage. However, I can connect my phone and it still acts like a mass storage, but it uses the MTP protocol. I can't simply disable all USB ports, since I have USB keyboards and mice. I was given advice by a friend that the way he usually solves this issue is simply super gluing the USB ports shut. This sounds a bit extreme. What are my options?

Comment: How did you disable the USB Mass Storage?  Are you sure that's working? (IE: if you plug a regular USB flash drive in right now, does it get blocked?)

Comment: Related from over on ServerFault: [Disable writing to “portable media player”](http://serverfault.com/questions/432805/disable-writing-to-portable-media-player)

Comment: @techie007 Yes, I've tested it thoroughly. Mass storage is in its entirety disabled.

Comment: Surely this can be done in the group policy editor.

Comment: @Moab Not that I've found. Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by setting the policy `WPD Devices: Deny read access` within `System\Removable Storage Access` to "Enabled" and this should block all the portable devices.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an elegant solution and would have to be performed for each MTP device, by changing the driver used by the device you can have it use the usb mass storage driver, which you have blocked.

http://eugeneboon.com/the-quickest-way-to-disable-mtp-media-player/

Comment: No danger of link rot here?

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer and include the info, I will do it when I have time.